# C++ associative array with arbitrary types for values

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, boost

What is the best way to have an associative array with arbitrary value types for each key in C++?

Currently my plan is to create a "value" class with member variables of the types I will be expecting. For example:

```
class Value {

    int iValue;
    Value(int v) { iValue = v; }

    std::string sValue;
    Value(std::string v) { sValue = v; }

    SomeClass *cValue;
    Value(SomeClass *v) { cValue = c; }

};

std::map<std::string, Value> table;
```

A downside with this is you have to know the type when accessing the "Value". i.e.:

```
table["something"] = Value(5);
SomeClass *s = table["something"].cValue;  // broken pointer
```

Also the more types that are put in Value, the more bloated the array will be.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: BTW, a std::map is not a hash table; it's usually implemented as a red-black tree, but in any case, the keys are kept in order. There is std::tr1::unordered_map, which is usually implemented as a hash table.

Comment: Chris, thanks for pointing that out. I'm now calling it an "associative array".

Comment: related: ["what is the point of heterogenous arrays?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534612/what-is-the-point-of-heterogenous-arrays)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/variant.html) seems exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Your approach was basically into the right direction. You *will* have to know the type you put into. You can use `boost::any` and you will be able to put just about anything into the map, as long as you know what you put into:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any> table;
table["hello"] = 10;
std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(table["hello"]); // outputs 10
```

Some answers recommended the use of `boost::variant` to solve this problem. But it won't let you store arbitrary typed values in the map (like you wanted). You have to know the set of possible types before-hand. Given that, you can do the above more easily:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, std::string, void*> variant_type;
std::map<std::string, variant_type> table;
table["hello"] = 10;
// outputs 10. we don't have to know the type last assigned to the variant
// but the variant keeps track of it internally.
std::cout << table["hello"];
```

That works because `boost::variant` overloads `operator<<` for that purpose. It's important to understand that if you want to save what is currently contained in the variant, you still have to know the type, as with in the `boost::any` case:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, std::string, void*> variant_type;
std::map<std::string, variant_type> table;
table["hello"] = "bar";
std::string value = boost::get<std::string>(table["hello"]);
```

The order of assignments to a variant is a runtime property of the control flow of your code, but the type used of any variable is determined at compile time. So if you want to get the value out of the variant, you have to know its type. An alternative is to use visitation, as outlined by the variant documentation. It works because the variant stores a code which tells it which type was last assigned to it. Based on that, it decides *at runtime* which overload of the visitor it uses. `boost::variant` is quite big and is not completely standard compliant, while `boost::any` is standard compliant but uses dynamic memory even for small types (so it's slower. variant can use the stack for small types). So you have to trade off what you use.

If you actually want to put objects into it which differ only in the way they do something, polymorphism is a better way to go. You can have a base-class which you derive from:

```
std::map< std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Base> > table;
table["hello"] = boost::shared_ptr<Base>(new Apple(...));
table["hello"]->print();
```

Which would basically require this class layout:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() { }
    // derived classes implement this:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Apple : public Base {
public:
    virtual void print() {
        // print us out.
    }
};
```

The [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) is a so-called smart pointer. It will delete your objects automatically if you remove them out of your map and nothing else is referencing them them anymore. In theory you could have worked with a plain pointer too, but using a smart pointer will greatly increase safety. Read the shared_ptr manual i linked to.

Comment: That's the runtime-type-checking option. For a compile-time-type-checking option, there's also boost::variant (use with visitor pattern for a watertight static type-checked solution).

Comment: well, we talked about that in irc i think :) just for all others reading it: variant can only store a limited set of types, and if one wants to get a value out of an entry, one can use visitation (and will get at the value without knowing its type), but one cannot save the value anywhere.

Comment: because the decision what version of the visitor is called is done at runtime. the type of a variable, however, is determined at compile time. so you can't do SomeAutoDeducedType result = boost::apply_visitor( my_visitor(), u ); . all op() of a visitor got the same return type.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `Value` with `IntValue`, `StringValue`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a union with std::map?

Boost::variant provides typeless variables.

Altrnatively you could make all your Value data members private and provide accessors that return an error (or throw) if it isn't set.

Comment: You can use an union with std::map, but unions can only hold POD-type objects.

Answer (score 1):

A straight-forward optimisation would be to use a `union`, since you'll always only have one of the values as key.

A more complete solution would encapsulate some run time type information into a interface. Primarily "Which type is this?" and "How do I compare values for equality?" Then use implementations of that as key.

Comment: Unions can't hold std::string's

Comment: Indeed, g++ complains "error: member ‘std::string [...]’ with constructor not allowed in union" (amongst other things). My C++ is getting rusty :-/