# How to get value of getter setter method in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, react-native, getter-setter

I have read many question on here, but still i don't find any right answer of my case right now

so I have a code like this

`VisitReport.java`

```
public class VisitReport{
  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "VisitReport";

  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
  public static final String COLUMN_VisitPurpose = "VisitPurpose";
  public static final String COLUMN_VisitResult = "VIsitResult";

  private int id;
  private String VisitPurpose;
  private String VisitResult;

  public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
      "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
          + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
          + COLUMN_VisitPurpose + " TEXT,"
          + COLUMN_VisitResult + " TEXT,"
          + ")";

  public VisitReport() {
  }

  public VisitReport(
    int id,
    String VisitPurpose,
    String VisitResult
  ){
    this.id = id;
    this.VisitPurpose = VisitPurpose;
    this.VisitResult = VisitResult;
  }

  public int getId() { return id; }
  public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
  public String getVisitPurpose() { return VisitPurpose; }
  public void setVisitPurpose(String VisitPurpose) { this.VisitPurpose = VisitPurpose;}
  public String getVisitResult() { return VisitResult; }
  public void setVisitResult(String VisitResult) { this.VisitResult = VisitResult;}
}
```

`DatabaseHelper.java` (piece of code Im used)

```
  public VisitReport getVisitReport(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(VisitReport.TABLE_NAME,
        new String[]{
          VisitReport.COLUMN_ID,
          VisitReport.COLUMN_VisitPurpose,
          VisitReport.COLUMN_VisitResult,
        },
        VisitReport.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null){
      cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    VisitReport vr = new VisitReport(
      cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitReport.COLUMN_ID)),
      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitReport.COLUMN_VisitPurpose)),
      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitReport.COLUMN_VisitResult))
    cursor.close();
    return vr;
  }
```

I want pass the value to `react native` using `bridge module`, but I get an error

> `Cannot convert argument of type class mypackage.VisitReport`

here's the code I've tried :

```
@ReactMethod
public void getVisitReport(int id, Callback cb) {
  DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(reactContext);
  cb.invoke(db.getVisitReport(id));
}
```

Find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709070/what-is-cause-for-this-issue-cannot-convert-argument-of-type-class-org-json-jso) as my reference still I don't get what's the meaning of those because when i log the value of `getVisitReport()` i got `mypackage.VisitReport@12d960c9` and i don't know the meaning of this

am i doing something wrong? anyone can help me how to make it work?

Comment: getVisitReport() is returning an object. 'mypackage.VisitReport@12d960c9' is the string representation of that object.

Comment: @Goofynose so how can i get the value of this object?

Comment: Implement toString() to get the value of the object.

Comment: @flix what do you mean by value? I am guessing you want to access one of the object's attributes (`id`, `visitPurpose`, ...)? You can access those values by doing something like `db.getVisitReport(id).getVisitPurpose()`

Comment: @Goofynose i want to get all of those object value, but i dont know how, i think the value of those object something like `{id:0, visitPurpose:"bar", visitResult:"baz"}` -cmiiw

Comment: @ZakiAnwarHamdani have tried `toString()` but the Log show the same result

Comment: @flix you need to get those values individually, that or you put them into an array that holds all of them. If you do `toString()` on getVisitReport you are doing a string conversion onto the actual `VisitReport` object itself, hence why you get the `mypackage.VisitReport@12d960c9`. Have a look at this page https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access each value individually by doing

```
db.getVisitReport(id).getVisitPurpose
```

Or

```
VisitReport vr = db.getVisitReport(id); vr.getVisitPurpose
```

That is because `getVisitReport()` returns an *object*. An object is an instance of a class that holds a set of variables.

When you do `getVisitReport(id).toString()` you are doing a returning a *string representation* of the object itself, **not** its values.

If you want to get all the object's attributes at the same time you need to create a new method inside `VisitReport` which returns all of the attributes in, for example, an array of objects (since all objects in Java extend Object, see [How to declare an array of different data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363547/how-to-declare-an-array-of-different-data-types)).

Please make sure you read more about java and objects. Here is a good link:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Answer (score 1):

At a guess something like the following may work :-

```
VisitReport vr = db.getVisitorReport(id);
cb.invoke("ID=" +String.valueOfvr.getid()) + ", Purporse=" + vr.getVisitPurpose"); // etc
```

- This assumes that invoke can accept a String.